# I made an adapter, but it doesn't connect

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

I made an adapter to make a recycler view. However, an error occurs that the adapter is not connected continuously. I definitely made it, why can't I? I'm predicting that it's a thread problem, but I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

```
public class RoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvFloor;
    private FloorAdapter floorAdapter;
    public ArrayList<FloorData> globalfloors = new ArrayList<>();
    int totalFloor;
    private RoomApi roomApi;
    private DormitoryData dormitoryData;
    private DormitoryApi dormitoryApi;
    static SharedPreferences pref;
    Retrofit retrofit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);
        pref = getSharedPreferences("token",0);
        init();

        rvFloor = findViewById(R.id.rvFloors);
    }

    private void init(){
        roomApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(RoomApi.class);

        dormitoryApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(DormitoryApi.class);


        Call<DormitoryData> callGetDormitory = dormitoryApi.get_dormitory(getToken());
        Callback<DormitoryData> callback = new Callback<DormitoryData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DormitoryData> call, Response<DormitoryData> response) {
                dormitoryData = response.body();
                totalFloor = dormitoryData.getStory();

                for(int i=0; i< totalFloor; i++){
                    FloorData temp = new FloorData();
                    temp.setFloorNum(i+1);
                    globalfloors.add(temp);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i<totalFloor; i++){
                    //해당 층에 있는 방들을 불러옵니다. 없을 수도 있어요.
                    Call<List<RoomData>> callRoomListByFloor = roomApi.getRooms_byFloor(getToken(), i+1);
                    if (callRoomListByFloor == null)
                        continue;
                    final FloorData floor = globalfloors.get(i);

                    //층에 있는 방들 정보를 불러옵니다.
                    Callback<List<RoomData>> callback2 = new Callback<List<RoomData>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<List<RoomData>> call, Response<List<RoomData>> response) {
                            floor.setRooms((ArrayList<RoomData>) response.body());
                            floorAdapter = new FloorAdapter(globalfloors, RoomActivity.this);
                            LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(RoomActivity.this);
                            rvFloor.setLayoutManager(manager);
                            rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);
                            floorAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FloorAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                                    FloorData floor = globalfloors.get(position);
                                    RoomData newRoom = new RoomData();
                                    floor.finalRoomNum++;
                                    newRoom.setRoomNum(floor.finalRoomNum);
                                    floor.rooms.add(newRoom);
                                    rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);
                                    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();


                                    json.addProperty("floor", position+1);
                                    json.addProperty("roomNum", newRoom.getRoomNum());

                                    Call<ResponseData> call = roomApi.add_room(getToken(), json);
                                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
                                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                                Toast.makeText(RoomActivity.this,response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if(response.body() == null){
                                                    Toast.makeText(RoomActivity.this,"알 수 없는 에러입니다. 개발자에게 문의하세요",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                            }else{
                                                Toast.makeText(RoomActivity.this,response.message().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                                            Log.e( "onFailure: ",t.getMessage() );
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<RoomData>> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(RoomActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    };
                    callRoomListByFloor.enqueue(callback2);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DormitoryData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        callGetDormitory.enqueue(callback);



    }
    public static String getToken(){
        return pref.getString("token","");
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows. RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the error already said what went wrong here. Did you try to add your adapter to your `RecyclerView` `rvFloor` at the `onCreate`?

If not, you can do is set a new adapter to provide child views on demand. Since setting the adapter once on the `onCreate` will do the job, and i think you should also call `init()` after defining the views

```
rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);
```